# 2 Finger scrolling in Notepad++ switches Tabs (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04

In Notepad++ (version 7.6.1) scrolling with 2 fingers will switch to the next file in the next tab when the EOF is reached.

Expected behaviour:
When scrolling to the EOF the scrolling stops (and does not switch to the next file(s) in a loop)

Remarks:
When I disable "2 finger scrolling" in the Ubuntu settings and enable "Edge Scrolling" the scrolling works as expected (stop on EOF).

Answer (score 0):

I found scrolling in notepad++ to be extremely sensitive to horizontal scroll, causing the scrolling through tabs when scrolling with two fingers. A fix for this while keeping two finger scroll is to disable horizontal scrolling only, which I managed by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130184/888366):

1. Install "libinput-tools" (this package name is slightly different from 16.04) and dependencies in terminal by running the following commands:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install libinput-tools`

2. Then enter the following line in terminal

`sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

3. The file will open in text editor. In the touchpad section, just before the line indicating the end of the section, add the following line:

`Option "HorizontalScrolling" "False"`

4. Save and close the configuration file and restart. Horizontal scrolling should be disabled.